# ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Use getter,setter - C#

Tags: c#, setter, getter

I need to create a class `Person`, that has fields:
`name`, `surname` and `salary`.
If the `salary` is lower than 0, I get the exception:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Use getter,setter

I tried with:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    string surname { get; set; }
    private int salary;
    public int Salary
    {
        get
        {
            return salary;
        }
        set
        {
            if (salary < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("salary", "wyplata ma byc wieksza niz 0");
            }
            else
            {
                salary = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in main:

```
Employee tmp = new Employee("michal", "jakowski", -1400);
```

Comment: You need `if (value< 0)`

Comment: Also it would be better to make surname public like `public string surname { get; set; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, when you check `if (salary < 0)`, the field `salary` is not yet updated with `value`. So instead you need to check whether `value` is less than `0`.

```
public int Salary
{
    get
    {
        return salary;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("salary", "wyplata ma byc wieksza niz 0");
        }
        else
        {
            salary = value;
        }
    }
}
```